# MySQL C API Crash on mysql_stmt_store_result()

Tags: c++, mysql, c, crash, gdb

I'm making a C++ wrapper for MySQL C API and have random crashes with prepared statement queries.

Everything works fine but with ~10% chance it crashes on mysql_stmt_store_result() . It seems that it only crashes when the same prepared statement is reused but I'm not sure. Same code can sometimes do like 50 queries on the same stmt one time and 5 queries the other. But I never had it crash on the first query.

Crash log:

```
#0  malloc_consolidate (av=0x7ffff0000020) at malloc.c:5137
        fb = 0x7ffff0000030
        maxfb = 0x7ffff0000070
        p = 0x8
        nextp = 0x8
        unsorted_bin = 0x7ffff0000078
        first_unsorted = 0x7ffff0000078
        nextchunk = 0x7ffff0011280
        size = 12672
        nextsize = 8176
        prevsize = <value optimized out>
        bck = 0x7ffff0000078
        fwd = 0x7ffff0000078
        __func__ = "malloc_consolidate"
#1  0x00007ffff5b06594 in _int_malloc (av=0x7ffff0000020, bytes=4064)
    at malloc.c:4373
        nb = 4080
        idx = 4026531960
        bin = 0x8
        victim = 0x7ffff0000020
        size = <value optimized out>
        victim_index = <value optimized out>
        remainder = <value optimized out>
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
        remainder_size = <value optimized out>
        block = <value optimized out>
        bit = <value optimized out>
        map = <value optimized out>
        fwd = <value optimized out>
        bck = <value optimized out>
        errstr = <value optimized out>
        __func__ = "_int_malloc"
#2  0x00007ffff5b08c70 in *__GI___libc_malloc (bytes=4064) at malloc.c:3661
        ar_ptr = 0x7ffff0000020
        victim = 0x30
        __func__ = "__libc_malloc"
#3  0x00007ffff7051ca2 in my_malloc () from /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007ffff704d5c5 in alloc_root () from /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007ffff702ca96 in cli_read_binary_rows ()
   from /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00007ffff702e5b7 in mysql_stmt_store_result ()
   from /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00000000005c3a79 in ResultSet (this=0x7ffff000e0d0,
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
    result=0x7ffff000e030, stmt=0x7ffff0008a10, fieldCount=3)
    at /var/coins/poolserver/cmake/src/server/shared/MySQL/QueryResult.cpp:34
        bind = 0x52bfc4c1
#8  0x00000000005c1b22 in MySQL::DatabaseConnection::Query (this=0x8e8b00,
    stmt=0x7ffff000de50)
    at /var/coins/poolserver/cmake/src/server/shared/MySQL/DatabaseConnection.cpp:247
        result = 0x7ffff000e030
        resultSTMT = 0x7ffff0008a10
        fieldCount = 3
```

As you can see stmt pointer is not null.

Portions of the code:

Query:

```
ResultSet* DatabaseConnection::Query(PreparedStatement* stmt)
{
    MYSQL_RES* result = NULL;
    MYSQL_STMT* resultSTMT = NULL;
    uint32 fieldCount = 0;

    if (!_Query(stmt, &result, &resultSTMT, fieldCount))
        return NULL;

    if (mysql_more_results(_mysql))
        mysql_next_result(_mysql);

    return new ResultSet(result, resultSTMT, fieldCount);
}

bool DatabaseConnection::_Query(PreparedStatement* stmt, MYSQL_RES** result, MYSQL_STMT** resultSTMT, uint32& fieldCount)
{
    if (!_mysql)
        return false;

    ConnectionPreparedStatement* cstmt = GetPreparedStatement(stmt->_index);

    if (!cstmt) {
        sLog.Error(LOG_DATABASE, "STMT id: %u not found!", stmt->_index);
        return false;
    }

    cstmt->BindParameters(stmt);

    MYSQL_STMT* mSTMT = cstmt->GetSTMT();
    MYSQL_BIND* mBIND = cstmt->GetBind();

    if (mysql_stmt_bind_param(mSTMT, mBIND))
    {
        uint32 lErrno = mysql_errno(_mysql);
        sLog.Error(LOG_DATABASE, "STMT Execute Error[%u]: %s", lErrno, mysql_stmt_error(mSTMT));

        if (_HandleMySQLErrno(lErrno))  // If it returns true, an error was handled successfully (i.e. reconnection)
            return Execute(stmt);       // Try again

        cstmt->ClearParameters();
        return false;
    }

    if (mysql_stmt_execute(mSTMT))
    {
        uint32 lErrno = mysql_errno(_mysql);
        sLog.Error(LOG_DATABASE, "STMT Execute Error[%u]: %s", lErrno, mysql_stmt_error(mSTMT));

        if (_HandleMySQLErrno(lErrno))  // If it returns true, an error was handled successfully (i.e. reconnection)
            return _Query(stmt, result, resultSTMT, fieldCount);       // Try again

        cstmt->ClearParameters();
        return false;
    }

    cstmt->ClearParameters();

    *result = mysql_stmt_result_metadata(mSTMT);
    fieldCount = mysql_stmt_field_count(mSTMT);
    *resultSTMT = mSTMT;

    return true;
}
```

ResultSet:

```
ResultSet::ResultSet(MYSQL_RES* result, MYSQL_STMT* stmt, uint32 fieldCount) :
_fieldCount(fieldCount), _currentRow(0)
{
    if (!result)
        return;

    if (mysql_stmt_store_result(stmt)) { // Crash here
        sLog.Error(LOG_DATABASE, "mysql_stmt_store_result, cannot bind result from MySQL server. Error: %s", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
        return;
    }

    /* further code */
}
```

These are only parts of the code involving a crash. Full code can be found here: https://github.com/Intel/poolserver/tree/master/src/server/shared/MySQL

I've been trying to solve this for 3 days but with no luck. Does anyone have an idea what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

> Everything works fine but with ~10% chance it crashes on mysql_stmt_store_result()

Any crash inside `malloc` or `free` is an almost sure sign of heap corruption (such as freeing non-heap memory, freeing something twice, or writing to memory after it's been freed or beyond the end of allocated block).

Run your program under [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org), and it will point you straight at your bug.

Or you could set the `MALLOC_CHECK_` environment variable, and have glibc abort when it detects corruption ([documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html)). This usually isn't as helpful as Valgrind, but is a quick way to confirm that you *do* in fact have heap corruption, and may provide sufficient clues for you to find and fix the bug.

Comment: With `MALLOC_CHECK_=1` it always crashes after the first query but without any stderr malloc message. Running gdb gives crash on simple int allocation. Although on valgrind I wasn't able to reproduce crash even after like 50 tries. Output: http://pastebin.com/PUzX5xGd

Comment: I found out that I'm only getting this crash when trying to query BIGINT (uint64). That explains valgrind invalid writes of 8 bytes. But everything happens in `mysql_stmt_execute()`. MySQL bug?

Comment: I was wrong. No matter what those valgrind errors still exist and program randomly crashes... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> with ~10% chance it crashes on mysql_stmt_store_result()

Have you ever try `mysql_stmt_free_result()` ?

ref: [20.6.11.14. mysql_stmt_free_result()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-stmt-free-result.html)

I came out this idea first just because I had encountered similar issue as yours recently.

Then I used `valgrind` to inspect my program, found that there were **over 500kB memory leak (definitely)** during calling `mysql_store_result()` repeatly, and the API page of `mysql_free_result()` said:

> When you are done with a result set, you must free the memory it uses by calling mysql_free_result().

So I modified my program to make sure that there **must** have a `mysql_free_result()` after I don't need the result of MySQL query. After that, my program only has 24bytes loss definitely, and it did not crash anymore.

I am not an expert of MySQL API, but I think that `mysql_stmt_store_result()` is similar to `mysql_store_result()`, maybe worth a try.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `mysql_stmt_free_result()`. I tried everything and couldn't fix it. Using simple queries instead of stmt now and it works fine except for the minor performance loss.